# Facebook SDK 3.1 and MonoTouch

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to use the new facebook sdk in my monotouch application?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MonoTouch bindings here: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook

Comment: It seems that is SDK 3.0.  
I was wondering about new SDK 3.1, with native UI.

Comment: You should be able to use the newer Obj-C library (the *.a file), and make the changes to the binding to support anything new.  Make sure to make a pull request if you change anything for the better.